# vue modal dropping frames when using transitions

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote a custom vue modal and it works perfectly fine on my pc but it keeps dropping frames on some mobile devices. It seems to be related to the transitions - without it works as expected (but looks and feels bad).

Even a transition with opacity 1 to opacity 0 causing lag in this case. (Any animation causing lag)

It's really simple code so it should work on every device - even mid range devices like the Samsung M31 can't display the animation without lag. (Even when the transition is only opacity or scale)

Menu.vue

```
    <Modal :is-open="testModalIsOpen" >
      test1
      test2
      test3
      test4
      test5
    <template #footer>
      <button @click="testModalIsOpen=false">BACK</button>
    </template>
  </Modal>
```

Modal.vue

```
<template>
  <transition name="rpg-modal__transition">
    <div class="rpg-modal" v-if="isOpen" :class="classes">
      <div class="rpg-modal__backdrop"></div>
      <div class="mx-auto rpg-modal__content-wrapper">
        <div class="rpg-modal__box" style="background-color: #0b1b3d">
            <div>
              <div class="rpg-modal__body">
                <slot/>
              </div>
              <div class="rpg-modal__footer d-flex justify-content-end">
                <slot name="footer"/>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import {computed} from "@vue/reactivity";

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: {
    isOpen: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    autoPadding: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const classes = computed(() => ({
      'rpg-modal--auto-padding': props.autoPadding
    }));

    return {
      classes,
    };
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.rpg-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  $transition-duration: 0.3s;

  &__transition {
    &-enter-active, &-leave-active {
      transition: all $transition-duration;
    }

    &-enter-from, &-leave-to {
      opacity: 0;
      filter: blur(5px);
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
  }

  &__backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  &__content-wrapper {
    max-width: 64vh;
    margin: auto;
  }

  &__box {
    $boxMargin: 13px;
    position: relative;
    margin: $boxMargin;

    max-height: calc(100vh - #{$boxMargin * 2});
    border-radius: 15px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    box-shadow: #00000073 0 0 10px;
  }

  &--auto-padding &__body {
    padding: 12px;
  }

  &__footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 9px;

    > * {
      margin: .25rem;
    }
  }

  &__close {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: rgb(62 62 62);
    box-shadow: #00000052 2px 2px 5px;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    right: 17px;
    top: 17px;
    transition: background-color 200ms;

    &:hover {
      background-color: #9f3e3e;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

[image]

Hope anyone can help & thanks for any answers!

Comment: I'm not an expert on mobile frames performance, but I'd maybe check testing with different animations? If not, maybe test same component using a different framework see how it performs.

Comment: I've tried different animations. Even simple ones like opacity 1 to opacity 0 causing lag. But only in this Modal component and I can't get the reason why.

Comment: If it's only in this Modal component then I'd check what's causing the lag in this component. Or write a new component testing animations, maybe there's a stage at your code where it's slowing down. Actually I see transition durations, check that you're using these properly, the lag could be the transition-duration you added.

Comment: a blur filter is expensive

Comment: I tried the modal without blur filter. No difference. It work perfect when I don't use any transition. It just appears and disappears without lag. If I use any transition (opacity, transform or blur...) the lag comes back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the will-change property?

> The will-change property in CSS optimizes animations by letting the
> browser know which properties and elements are just about to be
> manipulated, potentially increasing the performance of that particular
> operation.
> [from here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/)

So, try this:

```
.rpg-modal{
  will-change: transform, opacity, filter;
}
```

Also, set the initial value of the modal, the opacity:0 and the others...

Answer (score 0):

Is this why my spinner isn't working?

```
<b-modal>
  <b-card>
    <my-spinner v-if="loading" />
    <my-content content="myData" />
  </b-card>
</b-modal>

mounted() {
  this.loading = true
  this.readSomeData()
    .then(response => {
      this.myData = response.data
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.loading = false
    })
}
```

Note. I even added a setTimeout of 5s before fetching data, and spinner only wants to display after data fetch. also tried putting this.loading = true inside a `this.$nextTick(() => this.loading = true )` did not work either.

Comment: set the timeout to 10s. looks like the spinner does work after about 3 seconds of setting boolean to true. strange that it's taking longer to set the spinner than it is to make the api call.